# Java Programing error in cmd

Tags: java

```
import PPP.*;
public class Main{

   public static void main(String args[]){
      PP obj=new PP();
      obj.Show();
   }
}
```

**this simple program gives error :**

```
cannot access PP where PPP(Package) only contains a class file (PP.class) and it's on desktop
also Main.java is on desktop.
```

Comment: Did you first compile the package?

Comment: Specifying the error and providing a stacktrace would help.

Comment: did you put PP.class under PPP package ?

Comment: Yes i first complie the package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to right `package PP;` in your class PP

Here it is your revised code

```
package PPP;

public class PP
{

    public static void main(String...a)
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
    public void show()
    {
    System.out.println("hello");
    }

}
```

and here your main class

```
import PPP.*;

public class Main{

   public static void main(String args[]){
      PP obj=new PP();
      obj.show();
   }
}
```

it will help you